# how can i desgin this each layer in single view

Tags: ios, iphone

This values get from web servies. Totally i want to show 4 layer to display[i show here only 2 layer]. some times in web servies values are come more means the layer become big and show the values.same and anther 3 layers are displayed. help me..!

[image]

Comment: where have you been stuck during the implementation?

Comment: i dnt knw how to implement this in one single view with tatol four layer help me...

Comment: if you have not done anything, I guess none of us would do the implementation instead of you and for you......

Comment: can u help to do this...

Comment: give your client's contact and I will negotiate with them about doing it. :)

Comment: @holex lol. Please take note with my answer though. I'd hate to think that this would end up on an iPhone screen no matter who did it.

Comment: @Fogmeister, I don't think either it is the entire layout, I'd image it is a part of some bigger thing only, but I'm still not seeing the difficulty to implement such feature, so I'm silently waiting for the sequel and catching where the trick is. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIScrollView` or `Freeform` make it independent means don't use static value make it dynamic whatever number of layers you are getting from server and according to that adjust content size of UIScrollView.

Comment: can u say clear i dnt understand... or any sample code for this

Answer (score 0):

First of all. This view (and design) doesn't really follow any iOS consistency. The [Apple human interface guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/) are there to help you with finding the correct way to do something.

Right...

Do you need to show all the options at the same time? i.e. do you need all four "layers" on the screen at the same time? If so, why? What is the user supposed to do with this screen?

Is the user selecting one option from each layer? Multiple options from each layer? etc...

With either of these I would go down the route of using a `navigation controller` with a single `UITableViewController` to display each layer.

So, the user gets a nice list of options...

> dumbell
>
> E-Zbar
>
> cable
>
> barbel
>
> ...

And selects one (or many) of them.

Then the second "layer" is pushed onto the navigation stack and the user gets another nice list...

> incline
>
> decline
>
> close-grip
>
> rotating
>
> ...

This way the user has to only concentrate on one task and each list is deployed nicely and readably for them.

If I was a user and was presented with a big list of buttons like your design I wouldn't know what I was supposed to do.